# How to change Quarkus Json log timestamp field name?

Tags: quarkus

In previous versions of Quarkus Json logging you where able to set `quarkus.log.console.json.fields.timestamp.field-name=appTimestamp`

In the current version this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: If something used to work and doesn't anymore, please open an issue on Github. It would also be very helpful to include a sample application that exhibits the problematic behavior.

Comment: Actually I figured it out the Quarkiverse JSON Loging extension is not compatible with 2.x or doesn't seem maintained either. I opened an issue there...

Answer (score 0):

So it ended up being a versioning/documentation thing. The Quarkus code wizard was referencing an older version.

It has been tracked here: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-logging-json/issues/178 and subsequently fixed.